# Shared controller for frontend and backend actions in Magento

Tags: magento-1.6, controllers

I am using same controller for front-end and back-end action, everything works fine except setting global messages when redirect back to desired admin page.

I have used standard admin session handler to set messages for admin actions:

```
$notifierObject = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
```

PS:

1. Controller being called is of front-end type.
2. Redirected admin page is an order view page.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Customer action : my.testdomain.com/modulename/controllerfrontname/action1 is called when form is submitted.

Similar form is there in admin sales order view page.
Admin form submit action : my.testdomain.com/modulename/controllerfrontname/action1 , as you can see the same action is called.

frontName of admin and frontend routers is the same - modulename.(But I guess, this is not causing any problem)

I am successfully getting redirected back to admin sales order view page, but without any global messages that I have set in $notifierObject of admin session. That's the only problem.

Comment: As answers to this question suggests that this is not a proper way to avoid redundancy even though your logic part works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is somehow unclear, but I can give you one hint.
Don't use the same controller for frontend and backend.
you should have 2 of them because they serve 2 different purposes.
If you don't want to duplicate the code, out the common methods in a helper and call them in the different controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt suggestion.. and yes, moving common piece of code to helper for both controllers to use it, seems perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marius answer, sharing a controller between *frontend* and *adminhtml* is actually quite impossible.

For the controllers to work *adminhtml* needs to extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` while the *frontend* controller needs to extend `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`.

Depending on what kind of code is shared between the two controllers it should either be moved to a `Helper` or a `Model`

Answer (score 0):

If by your question you mean you are using the same `frontName` for both a frontend and backend router in your `config.xml` then you will get issues when routing requests - Magento won't neccessarily route to correct admin or frontend controller.  A better setup is to use the existing admin router for your admin controller requests, and define a new router for frontend requests.  Doing it this way also allows you to easily distinguish between an admin, and a frontend request.  So in config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NameSpace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
       </routers>
       ...
   </frontend>
   ...

    <admin>
        ...
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <NameSpace_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">NameSpace_Module</NameSpace_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
        ...
    </admin>
    ...
</config>
```